# java generics: Formal type "? extends MyClass" cannot be used for a call to "T get(Class<T> aClass)

Tags: java, generics

I have a class hierarchy (simplified) like:

```
Identifiable <- MemoOwner <- Antrag
```

which - BTW - represent DB entities.

I have a generic method which can fetch the entity type safe by the ID (done by hibernate):

```
public <T extends Identifiable> T getById(Class<T> clazz, Number id)
{
    return (T) getSession().get(clazz, id);
}
```

In a business layer I have follwing method:

```
public MemoOwner loadMemoOwner(final int aId, final FinanzhilfeType aType)
{
    Class<? extends MemoOwner> clazz = aType.getMemoOwnerClazz();
    ...
}
```

where the given FinanzhilfeType is an enum with associated member "MemoOwnerClazz" of type Class<? extends MemoOwner>. Depending on the type the final entity class can be different.

I would like call my generic method like (replacing above three dots):

```
    return myLoggingDbService.getById(clazz, aId);
```

But eclipse compiler complains:

```
The method getById(Class<T>, Number) in the type PersistenceService is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#2-of ? extends MemoOwner>, int)
```

I overcomed this situation by using an if-cascade:

```
    if ( clazz == Antrag.class )
    {
        return myLoggingDbService.getById(Antrag.class, aId);
    }

    if ( clazz == Vereinbarung.class )
    {
        return myLoggingDbService.getById(Vereinbarung.class, aId);
    }
    ....
```

which is not really satisfying because it is not generic.

I understand that the java generics are a compile time construct. But I do not understand why the compiler does not accept the type "Class<? extends MemoOwner>" for the formal Class<T> parameter. IMO my desired call is type safe also at runtime, because

- hibernate instatiates the entity using given class (runtime dynamic)
- the instantiated class is always a descendant of type MemoOwner (compile time generics), and can be assigned to the return value of my business method.

Why the compiler doesn't accept this generic type?

Comment: Hmm, what version of Eclipse and Java are you using? I did a quick test with some static classes and mocks and my Eclipse 4.11 running Java 8 doesn't complain. Unless I'm missing something this should work - could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: As @Thomas explained, this DOES in fact work. Can you pre-box the int, because that might be the problem. Something like Integer.valueOf(aId) instead of aId.

Comment: Same error message when I box the int as rzwitserloot suggested. Eclipse version 2018-12 (4.10.0), using JDK jdk1.8.0_u201-x64 on windows 7. I'll try a minimal example.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that a minimal example does compile (and correctly execute). And finally I found also the reason why my real code does not compile. I simplified a little bit too much in my question. The type hierarchy is much more complex, and it turned out, that Identifiable and MemoOwner are just interfaces, and the final class Antrag implements both. BUT: MemoOwner does not derive from Identifiable. And this is the reason why it didn't compile. What you mean, shall I delete the post or explain my mistakens?